# Disabling 2 future dates for reports

Tags: javascript

I want to limit the selection of date ranging from the past date and current date. The future dates must be disable. My "From Date" is functioning well, but the "To Date" is not. Does my Javascript code for To date is wrong?

**Js Code**

```
<script>
 $(function() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({maxDate: '+0d'});
 })
 $(function() {
 $("#datepicker1").datepicker1({maxDate: '+0d'});
 })</script>
```

**Hmtl Code**

```
<p>From Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>To Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
```

See my practice in this website:

https://jsfiddle.net/vr06um2a/

Comment: w3schools doesn't save your attempts. If it does then your attempt doesn't exist on that link. Try https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vr06um2a/   here it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `datepicker1` (extra '1') instead of `datepicker` for the 2nd function.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({maxDate: '+0d'});
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({maxDate: '+0d'});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help I really appreciate it this answer. This code is what I was looking for. Thank you again.